# Ionic 4, Azure Active Directory B2C in with Google as identity provider

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-active-directory, ionic4, google-signin, capacitor

this topic is about the combination of **Ionic 4** + *Capacitor* + **Azure Active Directory B2C** + **Native Application**

I am working inside an Ionic 4 project and i am using Azure Active Directory B2C as login provider.

Unfortionally, trying to add Google as login provider leads to the following problem:

https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-ad-b2c-google-signin-issue/

Google does not support webviews anymore.

Is there any way to open the login mask from Azure B2C with the embedded browser and only the external Google login with an external browser? I feel like i am forced to open the whole login process with the system browser if I want to use the google login service, which is no option because of the missing option in hiding the URL bar for that external browser.

Because I need a way in open the login mask without the toolbar. The page should look like a clean login mask, so the user does not get the feeling of leaving the application.

Did anyone experience this issue before and found a way in solving it? What I want is the following behaviour:

- From the native app the user should be able to open the login mask from Azure and feel like not leaving the app. So this login mask should be opened inside an webview or inapp browser because I think there is no way in manipulating the system browser to hide the URL bar.
- Then, if the user decides to use the google identy provider to login, the system browser can be used, best would be inside a pop up window

I would appreciate if someone has a solution for this problem.

Best regards

Comment: Did you find a solution?